# Join on datasourse on init Dynamics ax

Tags: datasource, axapta, x++

Does anyone know how to join 2 tables on dataSourceTable? I mean I have 2 fields on a grid and I filter a table with that fields, but I dont have idea how to do that, I have an executeQuery where I get the fields and I send them to the init ..

This is my code ..

executeQuery:

```
FilterGrid_1.value(queryValue(ComboBox_1.valueStr()));
FilterGrid_2.value(queryValue(ComboBox_2.valueStr()));
```

Init:

```
 FilterGrid_1=this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(Table_1)).addRange(fieldNum(Table_1,ID_Table1));
```

I have another filter but I dont know how to join it, and I think its not necesary

```
FilterGrid_2=this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(Table_2)).addRange(fieldNum(Table_2,Table2_Field));
```

Comment: Hi, In your case in init method you are adding range and in executequery method you are assigning the range value to filter. Adding range is like same as adding where clause in select query and multiple range is same as where clause with && conditions and you don't need other joins.

Answer (score 0):

[Auto joining](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa852141.aspx) on datasources is usually done without any code using [table relations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190076.aspx).
The relation between the the tables is defined on the child table.
To verify that all relation fields is correctly filled, use the [Best Practice Check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/aa874347.aspx) on the tables.

On the form child dataset set the `JoinSource` attribute to the parent datasource. Additionally you may set `LinkType` or `DelayActive`, but if you use two grids, you are better served with the default values of `Delayed` and `Yes`.

If you insist on doing it by code (say you may not change the tables), use the [addDynaLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/querybuilddatasource.adddynalink.aspx) if using delayed join, use [addLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/querybuilddatasource.addlink.aspx) if you are using inner or outer joins.